# MongoDB depends on ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I tried to startup mongod and I get this type of errors:

```
/Users/myuser/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/myuser/.rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/Users/myuser/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/myuser/.rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0
```

Why does mongoDB need ruby? and what does this mean exactly...

Comment: how are you starting up mongoDB

Comment: MongoDB definitely doesn't depend on Ruby normally. So, something else is going on ...

Comment: I'm simply running `mongod` and after a bit I get those errors. it works fine after I change up the rvm to use 2.0 (`rvm use 2.0`) ... not sure why that makes it work..

Comment: Are you perhaps getting the `rvm` errors after changing to a certain project directory? I would check if you have any [`.rvmrc` files](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc), as these can run automatically when you open a new shell or change to a project directory. If an rvm upgrade fixed the problem, maybe there was a `.rvmrc` file which assumed a newer version of `rvm`. As noted by WiredPrairie, MongoDB definitely doesn't depend on Ruby in a normal install.

Comment: I don't seem to find any `.rvmrc` anywhere.

Comment: and I've only seen this error when I tried running `mongod`, and not with anything else like `npm`, `node`, or `mongo`

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by "simply running mongod"? What [command line options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/) are you specifying? Where are you seeing these errors - on stdout? In a log? What else are you seeing before you get these errors? A little more context like this will help us better understand the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I just started up mongodb, using the command `mongod` in the terminal (osx), it churns for a minute or then stops and prints out those errors to stdout. I have set the default rvm version and everything works fine..I will check for `.rvmrc` files that might be a good direction. Just really curious why rvm/ruby is trying to do something